# How to do R dplyr's do in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split my pandas DataFrame into groups and then run a complex function on each chunk. The complex function returns for each chunk a DataFrame with arbitrary number and names of columns and an arbitrary number   of rows. I would like those result DataFrame to be combined after the operation. In R I am able to do this with

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df = tribble(
  ~g,  ~c1, ~c2,
  "a",   1,   6,
  "a",   2,   7,
  "b",   3,   8,
  "b",   4,   9,
  "b",   5,  10
)

myfct <- function(x, y){
  data.frame(c1 = x,
             c2 = y,
             res = c(x * y, x + y, x / y),
             type = c('mult', 'add', 'div'))
}

df %>% group_by(g) %>% do(myfct(.$c1, .$c2))
```

with the result being

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 5]
Groups: g [2]

       g    c1    c2        res   type
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <fctr>
1      a     1     6  6.0000000   mult
2      a     2     7 14.0000000    add
3      a     1     6  7.0000000    div
4      a     2     7  9.0000000   mult
5      a     1     6  0.1666667    add
6      a     2     7  0.2857143    div
7      b     3     8 24.0000000   mult
8      b     4     9 36.0000000    add
9      b     5    10 50.0000000    div
10     b     3     8 11.0000000   mult
11     b     4     9 13.0000000    add
12     b     5    10 15.0000000    div
13     b     3     8  0.3750000   mult
14     b     4     9  0.4444444    add
15     b     5    10  0.5000000    div
```

This - of course - is only an example.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need `apply` - check also [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
def myfct(x):
    print (x)
    return pd.DataFrame({'mult':x['c1'] * x['c2'], 
                          'add':x['c1'] + x['c2'], 
                          'div':x['c1'] / x['c2'],
                          'g':x.name,
                          'c1': x['c1'],
                          'c2':x['c2']})

df = df.groupby('g')['c1','c2'].apply(myfct)
print (df)
   add  c1  c2       div  g  mult
0    7   1   6  0.166667  a     6
1    9   2   7  0.285714  a    14
2   11   3   8  0.375000  b    24
3   13   4   9  0.444444  b    36
4   15   5  10  0.500000  b    50
```

Also for reshape is possible use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.groupby('g')['c1','c2'].apply(myfct)
       .melt(id_vars=['g','c1','c2'], value_name='res', var_name='type')
print (df)
    g  c1  c2  type        res
0   a   1   6   add   7.000000
1   a   2   7   add   9.000000
2   b   3   8   add  11.000000
3   b   4   9   add  13.000000
4   b   5  10   add  15.000000
5   a   1   6   div   0.166667
6   a   2   7   div   0.285714
7   b   3   8   div   0.375000
8   b   4   9   div   0.444444
9   b   5  10   div   0.500000
10  a   1   6  mult   6.000000
11  a   2   7  mult  14.000000
12  b   3   8  mult  24.000000
13  b   4   9  mult  36.000000
14  b   5  10  mult  50.000000
```

Comment: Ok, I think this is a step in the right direction, but I don't see a groupby column anymore. Can we bring that back?